# How can I load divSecond before divFirst?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say divSecond is below divFirst. I want to use JavaScript to make divSecond load before divFirst.

```
+------------+
|            |
|  divFirst  |
|            |
|  content   |
|            |
| divSecond  |
|            |
+------------+
```

I've gotten the following code but I can't figure out how to check.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    checkDiv();
});

function checkContainer () {
    if($('#divSecond').is(':visible'))){ 
    // If it's loaded
    // How to load it in the page..
}
```

Comment: Define "load before." As far as we can tell from your question, both are loaded with the same HTML page.

Comment: If you are referring to adding a div in the page you can use $('container').append('.divSecond') , check out jquery append/prepend/html

Comment: Improved indentation, changed some characters

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("#divFirst").hide();
    // Hiding it by default. better use CSS selector this purpose so that it won't be shown. 
    // #divFirst {display: none;}

    checkDiv();
});
```

Assuming you want to show `divFirst` only if `divSecond` is visible/shown

```
function checkContainer () {
    if($('#divSecond').is(':visible')){ 
        $("#divFirst").show();
    });
}
```